# Can not send multiple Modbus requests on the same TCP connection

Tags: tcp, poco, modbus

I am using the POCO C++ library for sockets and TCP connection.

When I open and close the connection for each request, all is normal :

```
Poco::Net::SocketAddress sa("192.168.2.55", 502);
Poco::Net::StreamSocket socket;

socket.connect(sa);
socket.sendBytes(/*set coil 5 to 1*/, 12);
socket.close();

socket.connect(sa);
socket.sendBytes(/*set coil 6 to 1*/, 12);
socket.close();

socket.connect(sa);
socket.sendBytes(/*set coil 7 to 1*/, 12);
socket.close();
```

Coils 5, 6, and 7 are set to 1 normally.

But when I send the 3 requests over the same TCP connection, only the first is taken :

```
Poco::Net::SocketAddress sa("192.168.2.55", 502);
Poco::Net::StreamSocket socket;

socket.connect(sa);

socket.sendBytes(/*set coil 5 to 1*/, 12);
socket.sendBytes(/*set coil 6 to 1*/, 12);
socket.sendBytes(/*set coil 7 to 1*/, 12);

socket.close();
```

Only the coil number 5 is set to 1.

Which one is better?
And what can I do in order to make the second one work?

Comment: Using Pseudo code makes it difficult to answer. Are you using different transaction  identifiers for each request?

Comment: @Brits Yes, I am incrementing the transaction id for each transaction

Comment: @Brits actually it is not a pseudo code, instead of the comment, there are the necessary bytes for changing a coil value at a specific address and a specific slave id.

for example: unsigned char bytes[12] = 
    { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x06, 0x01, 0x05, 0x00, 0x04, 0xFF, 0x00 };

Comment: I would term `/*set coil 5 to 1*/` pseudo code (it's not c++) and this is reason I had to ask about the transaction ID. The [modbus TCP standard](https://www.modbus.org/docs/Modbus_Messaging_Implementation_Guide_V1_0b.pdf) states "It is recommended to keep the TCP connection opened with a remote device and not to open and close it for each MODBUS/TCP transaction" so 1 connection is the way to go. I'd suggest processing the device response before sending a further request (not all devices support multiple simultaneous requests).

Comment: @Brits Yes that is ! "processing the device response before sending a further request". Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the comments its worth processing the device response before sending a further request. The [spec](https://www.modbus.org/docs/Modbus_Messaging_Implementation_Guide_V1_0b.pdf) states:

> The  number  of  requests  accepted  by  a  server  depends  on  its capacity  in  term  of  number  of  resources  and  size  of  the  TCP  windows.  In the  same  way  the  number  of  transactions initialized simultaneously by a client depends also on its resource capacity.
> This  implementation  parameter  is  called  "NumberMaxOfClientTransaction"  and  must  be  described  as  one  of  the  MODBUS  client  features. Depending  of  the  device  type  this  parameter can take a value from 1 to 16.

So some devices may only not support multiple simultaneous requests.

Regardless of the above it is worth processing the response because the device may be responding with an error.

*Note: Whilst you can implement the Modbus protocol yourself (its a fairly simple protocol) you may find one of the many available libraries of benefit (e.g. [macchina.io](https://docs.macchina.io/edge/IoT.Modbus.html),[EasyModbusTCP.NET](http://easymodbustcp.net/codesampleseasymodbustcp-net)).*